# Blender does not play audio track after restart

Tags: audio

I try to use Blender as a video editor.
I dropped 1 video, 1 mp3 and everything was ok - video plays, audio plays.
As soon as I restart Blender and go to last session video track is ok, but audio track has no sound.  Rendering also will have no sound.

What is it?

PS: if I render just after I dropped mp3 - there is sound in rendered video (as it is in preview window).

Comment: Check you haven't accidentally muted the strip, and try "update animation cache" in properties > scene > audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only when I pressed to recover last session.
If I open .blend file - everything was fine.
I noticed Blender was trying to open some file in /tmp dir. And it couldn't.